# Javascript - Pass parameter to function for use in getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parameters

Working on statistics that increment quickly to their final value when the element comes into view to make it look like the number is rising.

Having some trouble passing the parameters needed to determine which element is to be incremented, and what the final value is to determine when to stop incrementing the value.

```
function increment(elem, finalVal) {

    var currVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML, 10);
    if (currVal < finalVal) {
        value++;
        document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = currVal + "%";

        setTimeout(function() {
        increment(elem, finalVal);
        }, 40)
    }
};
```

Here's the codepen too to get the full picture:
http://codepen.io/BAWKdesign/pen/yePOGV

Comment: You are incrementing `value` which doesn't seem to be defined (unless you have it defined as a global or in a higher scope). Did you mean to increment `currVal`?

Comment: Just realised i was editing that pen and not a fork! that should be fixed, would you mind taking a look again please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tuar43m6/3/

Comment: Brilliant just updated my Codepen and it's working too, looks like that was the actual issue, sorry for the brainfart guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `value` is not used anywhere.

I assume your increment function should look like this

```
function increment(elem, finalVal) {
var currVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(4).innerHTML, 10);
if (currVal < finalVal) {
    currVal++;
    document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = currVal + "%";
    setTimeout(function() {
        increment(elem, finalVal);
    }, 40);
  }
};
```

Comment: Perfect, sorry about that, nothing logically wrong, I was just oblivious to renaming that variable from what i had called it before!

Answer (score 1):

1. replace `value++` with `currVal++`.
2. Remove the lines that set `elem` and `finalVal` as they are parameters.

Here's updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGOQEy)

Comment: Definitely, i'd been looking at it for a while, so guess my eye was missing it too